# Asynchronous loop iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a function `perform_function`. I want to perform it 1000 times. I would usually write a for-loop to do this e.g. ;

```
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
   [self perform_function]; 
}
```

But i want the function to finish before iterating to the next integer so it's asyncronous. How could i do this?

Comment: Your questions seems contradictory or I might be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `dispatch_async`, which will let you execute code in the background:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
     // insert for loop here
});
```